# cl-json decode-json getting plist keys as strings, not as symbols

Tags: json, common-lisp

I am trying to decode json data in Common Lisp using the library cl-json. But I have a problem : when using the `decode-json-from-string` function, with this data, for example

```js
{"Hello": "world"}
```

I get a plist that looks like this:

```lisp
(:*HELLO . "world")
```

But I want the accessor to be a symbol, not a string.

Answer (score 3):

`:*HELLO` is a symbol: it's a symbol in the keyword package.  How symbols are turned to and from JSON object keys is described in [the manual](https://common-lisp.net/project/cl-json/cl-json.html): the default encode and decoders map object keys onto symbols, doing a lot of fancy camel-case translation.  `*json-identifier-name-to-lisp*` & `*lisp-identifier-name-to-json*` are two variables which hold the default mapping functions, which are `camel-case-to-lisp` and `lisp-to-camel-case` respectively.  `*json-symbols-package*` controls the package where interning happens.

You can adjust any or all of these to do what you want.

Comment: It would be nice to say how to keep the original string. Would an identity function returning its input be enough?